# trying to save data from a list in a dictionary (in a more pythonic way)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension

when I try to create a dictionary from a list of list, python only saves the info from the last list within the list when I use comprehensions.

```
prediction_dict = dict()
for user_prediction in sliding:
    for cur_loc, prediction_list in user_prediction:
        prediction_dict[(cur_loc.user, cur_loc.time)] = prediction_list
        print prediction_dict
```

how can I achieve this in a more pythonic way, with list comprehension?

i try this:

```
prediction_dict = {(cur_loc.user, cur_loc.time): prediction_list for cur_loc, prediction_list in user_prediction for user_prediction in sliding}
```

but it only saves data of the last list within the lists?

why?

Comment: Can you give a sample of what ```sliding``` looks like?

Comment: Keep in mind that comprehensions are not always "more Pythonic" than loops. If a comprehension is very verbose or complex, a loop may be easier to read, and thus more Pythonic. (Of course there are differences of opinion over what is "too verbose or complex". Some folks would consider your example already too verbose for a comprehension.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the others have mentioned, your comprehension is not working because the `for` statements need to be switched. However, there is a simple reason as to why your code was doing what it was doing. If you do this:

```
del(user_prediction) #Ensure we aren't using a previously defined version
prediction_dict = {(cur_loc.user, cur_loc.time): prediction_list for cur_loc, prediction_list in user_prediction for user_prediction in sliding}
```

Then you will get an error like this:

```
NameError: name 'user_prediction' is not defined
```

So I'm guessing when you where trying it, you were doing something like this:

```
prediction_dict = dict()
for user_prediction in sliding:
    for cur_loc, prediction_list in user_prediction:
        prediction_dict[(cur_loc.user, cur_loc.time)] = prediction_list
        print prediction_dict

prediction_dict = {(cur_loc.user, cur_loc.time): prediction_list for cur_loc, prediction_list in user_prediction for user_prediction in sliding}
print prediction_dict
```

If you print the value of `user_prediction` after the `for` loops and before the comprehension, you will find it refers to the last entry in `sliding`. This wouldn't be a problem, except from the `NameError` we see that the comprehension as you have it is trying to use an old value rather than the new value you want to give it. What's going on behind the scenes is something like this:

```
prediction_dict = {}
loop_one_input = user_prediction
for cur_loc, prediction_list in loop_one_input:
    loop_two_input = sliding
    for user_prediction in loop_two_input:
        prediction_dict[(cur_loc.user, cur_loc.time)] = prediction_list
```

So as you can see, by the time `user_prediction` is reassigned to a new value (in the inner `for` loop) the outer `for` loop is already using the old value. This isn't exactly what's happening, but hopefully it gives you a good enough idea to understand *why* your dictionary comprehension was not working correctly.

Comment: I really like that you took the time to try to explain what's happening, instead of just a quick "you meant to do this instead". (Already worth an upvote from me.) I'm not 100% sold on the paragraph starting with "However, this meant..." and ending with "previous version of `user_prediction`." Not because I think it's wrong, but just because it's still confusing to me. I can't tell when you're talking about something in the explicit loop section of the code or in the comprehension section of the code. (Granted, OP didn't make this easy!)

Comment: @JohnY You're right, that paragraph was rather confusing. Does it seem clear now?

Comment: Much better! Probably about as good as it gets without actually writing out a trace and making this answer ten times longer.

Answer (score 2):

When converting a nested for loop to a nested list comprehension the outer loops need to come first, so it looks like you just need to switch the order of the iteration within your comprehension (broken up onto multiple lines for clarity:

```
prediction_dict = {(cur_loc.user, cur_loc.time): prediction_list
                   for user_prediction in sliding
                   for cur_loc, prediction_list in user_prediction}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it, change the order of for statements in the comprehension:

```
prediction_dict = {(cur_loc.user, cur_loc.time): prediction_list 
                   for user_prediction in sliding 
                   for cur_loc, prediction_list in user_prediction}
```